# need to send basename output to file

Tags: bash

Linux and bash novice.  I am creating a bash script to discover some stuff about a bunch of scripts.  I have this:

```
find /home/users/code -type f \( -name "*.sh" \) >> list1.txt
cat list1.txt | while read LINE;
do
   basename --suffix=".sh" "${LINE}";
done
```

That creates file list1.txt with the full path names, good so far.  The loop sends the list of file names to the terminal window.  Good.  How do I get that list of file names into a file so that I can create another few lines of code to do things with each of the file names.  I tried this

```
basename --suffix=".sh" "${LINE}" > list2.txt
```

with a few variations but that did not work out well in that list2.txt had only the name of the script or it has zero length.  How can this be done?

Edit 1 replaced by Edit 2:
I must have done something wrong but now the line: "done > list2.txt" provides what I need.  I will be working the other comments now.  Thank you.
Edit 3:
My reputation is insufficient to chat.  I replaced line

```
cat list1.txt | while read LINE
```

with

```
> list1.txt | while read LINE
```

and the result is list2.txt has zero length.

Comment: Put the `>list2.txt` on the end of the `done` to redirect *once* for the whole loop, so the file doesn't get rewritten from the top over-and-over.

Comment: BTW, it's much more efficient to take out the `cat list1.txt |` and put a `<list1.txt` after the `done`. That also avoids the bugs described in [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Comment: As another note, `while read` takes a lot more work to be reliable when used in conjunction with `find`; its output may *look* correct, but there are a bunch of corner cases in your code around names that start or end with spaces, contain literal backslashes, contain literal newlines, or are otherwise interesting. Consider `find /home/users/code -type f -name '*.sh' -printf '%f\0' | while IFS= read -r -d '' name; do printf '%q\n' "${name%.sh}; done` instead.

Comment: ...or, if you *really* want to use the `basename` command instead of letting the shell use builtin logic to do the same thing more efficiently, `find /home/users/code -type f -name '*.sh' -exec basename --suffix=.sh -- {} + >list2.txt`. Because the output of `basename` given multiple names to an instance is line-oriented, though, it has the same bugs that plague *any* attempt to store lists of literal filenames in a line-oriented format.

Comment: BTW, it's helpful if instead of "didn't work so well" you describe the specific *way* it didn't work so well (such as, in this case, resulting in an output file that only contains the basename of the last name processed).

Comment: Re:  ...or, if you really want to use the basename command ...

Comment: Oops, Return key immediately sends.  re: ...or, if you really want to use the basename command ...  I don't "really" have any preference, I am quite the novice at this so any suggestions will be appreciated.  Regarding the output did not work so well, on the last try list2.txt just had the name of the script.  I replaced "cat list1.txt " with exactly "<list2.txt" and and the script just provides the next prompt line.

Comment: Hard to say what went wrong at runtime without any logs. `bash -x yourscript` will log each line of execution as it takes place (doesn't include the redirections, but we don't strictly need them). If you want that log to include the values assigned by `read`, then consider a dummy command like `while read line; do : line="$line"; basename --suffix=".sh" "$line"; done <list1.txt >list2.txt` -- note the `: line="$line"`, which will cause the `set -x` logs to include each value of `line`.

Comment: I typed in:  "bash -x call3.sh"  and there is one line of output that contains:   " +read LINE"  followed by the prompt.  Where is the output log?  I don't see anything new in the current directory.  I am a novice with Linux and bash.

Comment: If it goes straight from `read LINE` to the prompt, that means there was nothing (well, no valid lines) to read -- ie. that `list1.txt` was empty (or at least didn't have one or more newlines; if you created it with `-print0` and didn't change your `read` to one intended to handle NUL-delimited names, that would do it).

Comment: BTW, all-caps names are used for variables meaningful to the shell itself; variable names with at least one lowercase character are guaranteed not to modify shell behavior when used by applications. See relevant POSIX spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph.

Comment: Oh -- you say you replaced `cat list1.txt` with `<list2.txt`? That should be with `<list1.txt`, of course. `>list2.txt` is the *output* side.

Comment: `> list1.txt | while read LINE` is wrong. It should be `while read line; do ...; done <line1.txt >list2.txt`. The redirections go *at the end*; `<` should be used for input, `>` should be used for output.

Comment: ...to explain why that happens, on its own, the command `> list1.txt` just blanks/empties `list1.txt`, so `> list1.txt | ...` pipes the output of that blanking/emptying command (which *has* no output, so it pipes an empty string) to the commands on the right-hand side of the pipeline.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't considering the complete pipeline I suggested up in the very 3rd comment? Go that route and you don't need a `list1.txt` or a `list2.txt` at all.

Comment: I saw the third post but I am a complete novice at bash and Linux, the comments do not allow line breaks, I was trying the more simple stuff, and flat out do not understand that long command line you wrote.  I am trying to do this one step at a time with the ability to look at each step and see what it does.  Maybe that way I can understand what I am doing.

Comment: One way to understand a pipeline is to use `tee` to store what went through it in parts. `set -x; find /home/users/code -type f -name '*.sh' -printf '%f\0' | tee test1.0sv | while IFS= read -r -d '' name; do : name="$name"; printf '%q\n' "${name%.sh}"; done` will run the pipeline but save a copy of the output from `find` in `test1.0sv` (a "null-separated-value" file), and will log all the commands as they run to stderr.

Comment: ...on a GNU system, you can use `cat -A test1.0sv` to look at the file with the NULs replaced with printable characters.